# How to use Axios to do a 2nd API get request call after componentDidMount, once the user interacts with your App?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using Axios to do make an API call a (get request) inside the life cycle method `componentDidMount`.

It's working fine, I'm getting my result and saving the data using setState.

```
componentDidMount(){
   axios.get("https://myAPI/v1/myAPI-Endpoint?myAPI-Key=12345678910abcdef")
     .catch(error => console.log('Error', error))
     .then(
       (response) => {
         let data = response.data;
         this.setState({
           myFetchedData: data
         });
       },
     )
}
```

- Then I use the data fetched to populate an autocomplete input, and once the user selects a value, I want to do another API call with the selected value

The question:

- Where should I do that 2nd API call now, I assume that I cannot do it in `componentDidMount` since the component is already mounted?
- So what is the best practice here? Where should I do an API call that is triggered by a user action?

Comment: Trigger onchange of autocomplete and call another api there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autocomplete component is likely to have some sort of event that fires when a selection was made (something like 'onChange', 'onSelect', etc, this depends on the component).

You could then do something like this (in your render function):

```
<AutoComplete
  onSelect={this.handleAutoCompleteSelect}
  …
/>
```

and then, inside the component class:

```
…
handleAutoCompleteSelect (value) {
  axios.get(apiEndpont, { value }) // Exact request depends on your api implementation
    .catch(…)
    .then(function (res) {
      // Process request result here
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, actually for some reason I had an error in the way I was using the API key... it was working in the first API call but not in the 2nd one